# ruby array of regex matches from collection

Tags: ruby, regex

In my root/app/models directory, I have a collection of files that match the following regex pattern:

```
/(.+)_field.rb/
```

In other words, a few files end with _field.rb. Now I want to return the matching part as an array, so I try the following:

```
 Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/models/*_field.rb"].select {|file| /(.+)_field.rb/.match(file) }
```

Unfortunately, it just returns the entire file path, not just portion I need (e.g. "abc_field.rb" should return "abc").

What am I doing wrong?

I am able to get this working the following way but still looking for something more elegant:

```
arr = []
Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/models/*_field.rb"].each {|file| arr << /.+\/(.+)_field.rb/.match(file)[1] }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This'll work:

```
foo = %w[ a_field.rb b_field.rb]
foo.map{ |f| f[/_field\.rb$/] = ''; f }
# => ["a", "b"]
```

or:

```
foo.map{ |f| f.sub(/_field\.rb$/, '') }
# => ["a", "b"]
```

or:

```
foo.map{ |f| f[0..-10] }
# => ["a", "b"]
```

or:

```
bar = '_field.rb'
foo.map{ |f| f[0..-(bar.size + 1)] }
# => ["a", "b"]
```

If you have a "path/to/file.ext" you can use [`File.basename`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/File.html#method-c-basename) to strip off the path portion:

```
foo = %w[ /path/to/a_field.rb /path/to/b_field.rb]
foo.map{ |p| File.basename(p) }
# => ["a_field.rb", "b_field.rb"]
```

If you have basenames and want to strip off their extensions, use [`File.extname`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/File.html#method-c-extname):

```
foo = %w[ /path/to/a_field.rb /path/to/b_field.rb]
bar = foo.map{ |p| 
  ext = File.extname(p)
  File.basename(p, ext) 
}
bar # => ["a_field", "b_field"]
```

Combine all that and you're home free.

Comment: One thing is this is still returning entire file path e.g. "/home/users/myapp/app/model/user" from "/home/users/myapp/app/model/user_field.rb" whereas I just want "user".

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
arr = Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/models/*_field.rb"]
arr.map { |f| f[/[^\/]+$/] }
```

On my computer:

```
arr = Dir["desktop/ruby_src/d*.rb"]
  #=> ["desktop/ruby_src/dp.rb", "desktop/ruby_src/dp134.rb"]
arr.map { |f| f[/[^\/]+$/] }
  #=> ["dp.rb", "dp134.rb"]
```